# GCM Broadcast Receiver differentiate between different requests

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I have a standard GCM Broadcast receiver. When I make a request to the server, I send my registration ID and username and a title. When I want to send a message from the server back to the phone, how do I make sure its to that specific title again? So far all examples I've seen seem to rely on 1 request.

In case I didn't explain it well enough :

User A registers on the GCM server and gets a gcm registration id
User A sends a request with the gcm registration id, title and their username to the server. 
Server sends a message back to the user. 
How do I make sure it is to that specific request instead of the user himself?

This is my broadcast receiver

```
public class GCMBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    Intent update = new Intent("update");
    update.putExtra("msg",extras.getString(AppConstants.MSG_KEY));

    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), GCMNotificationIntentService.class.getName());
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(update);
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    Log.d("ONRECEIVEWAKEFUL", "ONRECEIVEWAKEFUL");
    Log.d("ONRECEIVEWAKEFULMSG",String.valueOf(extras.getString(AppConstants.MSG_KEY)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
}
```

Do I need to set a filter or something?

EDIT This is where Im receiving the message from the gcm server

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(onNotice, new IntentFilter("update"));

    //Intent msg sent from Broadcast Receiver
    String str = getIntent().getStringExtra("msg");
```

Comment: Why did I get a -1? I hope someone can explain?

Comment: `How do I make sure it is to that specific request instead of the user himself` - it is still not clear what are you asking.

Comment: Like currently the user makes a request which sends a parameters such as gcm registration ID, username and title of the request to the server. I can pick up those details from the server and send a reply back to the phone. But If the user sends another request, how do I send a reply specifically for that request.

Comment: save gcm regid,name,title request in server side database..then pick up the request whatever you want from database.and send a reply for that request

Answer (score 0):

Your backend should hot only deal with sending messages but it should also handle some sort of "registration" of users/devices so you can tell which user uses which device. `registration Id` you receive on the device is something that does NOT take **user** into consideration - you need to deal with it yourself on your backend, and somehow connect registration id with **your** user.